# How to Save all my variables into file to restore the program from the same point C#?

Tags: c#, windows, deployment, save, savestate

i don't know if I'm explaining my self right but what i want is to save my program variables and information in one file and then start this file with this program.
**my idea is like a `.docx` file that opens with `MS Word`**
and if this available can anyone show how to do it and how to make the computer start `my program` when ever a file with a `.yaser` extension is opened
thanks in advance to anyone that helps me :)

Comment: Have you looked at the [`Settings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869.aspx) file?

Comment: You can use XML to store last data, then restore from that XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is save all the variables in a custom class serialize it using [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37609/Serialize-and-Deserialize-Objects-as-XML-using-Gen)  this might help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can put all the important data in a state class, and then serialize it to file in a binary, XML or JSON format. When your application is restarted, you can deserialize this file back to a class instance and use it.

For binary serialization look at BinaryFormatter, for XML - XmlSerializer, for JSON you can user JSON.Net

You may also need some plumbing code to rebuild caches, resubscribe to events, e.t.c.

Comment: Here is a sample for XmlSerializer - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813 , you can easily google the samples for other methods as well